# Using the file name as the parameter of the function and removing one list from another

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a code but probably the function part is not correct. I should make a function of the file name and then Return back to it.

Secondly, the has to be another function that removes the elements of `text2_words` from `text1_words`.

I have the code but I do not have a function for removing the `text2_words` list from `text1_words` and my function for the filename is not correct because I can not return to it.

**Expecting result:**

```
Insert name of the file:text.txt

Number of words in the text: 96

Number of unique words: 42

Hitta

din

nyhet

Stoff

nyheter

runt
.
.
.
```

**Code:**

```
import re

def common_words(filename, text2="vanligaord.txt"):

    text1=0
    infile_1= open("text.txt", "r")
    filename=text1
    text1=input('Insert name of the file:')

    text1=infile_1.read()



    for punctuation in '!,?,.,-':
        text1=text1.replace(punctuation, " ")
        text1_words=text1.split()


    print('Number of words in the text:', len(text1_words))

    infile_2= open("vanligaord.txt", "r",encoding='latin_1')
    text2= infile_2.read()
    text2_words=text2.split('\n')

    unique_words=[]
    for word in text1_words:
        if word not in text2_words:
            unique_words.append(word)


    print('Number of unique words:', len(unique_words))

 print ('\n'.join(unique_words))
```

**Expected Output Screenshot:**
[image: The expected output]

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Can you show the exact input files and expected output? Thanks.

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: Insert name of the file:text.txt \n
Number of words in the text: 96\n
Number of unique words: 42\n
Hitta
din
nyhet
Stoff
nyheter
runt
omkring
Kanske
nyligen
hänt
kommunen
skolan
kopplat
hållbarhet
berätta
Du
söka
aktuella
forskningsrapporter
nyheter
nationellt
koppla
bor
spinna
vidare
Eller
varför
skapa
egen
nyhet
enkätundersökning
viktig

Comment: Well, I have two text file: the first one is called 'text.txt 'and the second one which is a list of words is called ' vanligaord.txt'

Comment: Can you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032463/using-the-file-name-as-the-parameter-of-the-function-and-removing-one-list-from) with this information? This is unreadable. Thanks.

Comment: Is it good now?

Comment: No, sorry. Please put this *as text* in the question itself. Links to images are a total pain--I have to re-type everything in again, it wastes space and is unfriendly to those with screen readers.

Comment: I hope it is readible now